# SQL return only not empty columns from row as new row

Tags: php, sql, select, if-statement, subquery

I'm in the situation where my client e-mails me an excel-file with 50 columns of data extremely un-normalized. I then export it to CSV and upload into MySQL -- single table. The columns are for different ingredients (10 columns of data for each ingredient -- title, category, etc) and then 40 different columns for characteristics on each ingredients. So each ingredient in the table has all of these 50 columns even though every column doesn't apply for that ingredient.

My question is if I can create a SQL that selects only filled in characteristics for one selected ingredient and leaves out all of the other columns?

(I know that another option is to build my own CSV-parser that created multiple tables and then write SQL for them instead, but I wanna investigate solving this as is first. If that's not possible then I just have to face that and build a parser ;P)

This is as far as I came but this doesn't completely exclude columns not filled in (or that contains "nei".

```
SELECT 
IF(`Heving-vanlig-gjaerbakst` <> '' AND `Heving-vanlig-gjaerbakst` <> 'nei', `Heving-vanlig-gjaerbakst`, 'random') AS `test1`,
IF(`Frys-kort` <> '' AND `Frys-kort` <> 'nei', `Frys-kort`, 'random') AS `test2`
... and for the 38 other rows ...
FROM x
WHERE id = 123
```

And I'd rather not solve this in the PHP-code by skipping empty rows =P

Example row (column names first):

```
g1      gruppe              ug1         undergruppe             artnr   artikkel                beskrivelse                                             status  enhet   ansvar      prisliste   Heving-vanlig-gjaerbakst    Heving-soete-deiger Deig-stabilitet Smaksgiver  Saftighet   Krumme-poring   Skorpe  Volum   Konservering    Skjaerbarhet    Frys-lang   Frys-kort   Kjoel   Holdbarhet  E-fri   Azo-fri Mandler Aprikoskjerner  Helmiks Halvmiks    Base    Konsentrat  Utstrykning Bakefasthet Frukt-Baerinnhold   Slippegenskaper Hindre-koksing  Palmefri    Fritering   Smidighet   Baking  Kreming Roere   Fylning Dekor   Prefert Viskositet  Cacaoinnhold    Fet-innhold
100150  Bakehjelpemidler    100150200   Fiber/potetprodukter    10085   Potetflakes sekk 15 kg  Egnet til lomper, lefser, brød og annet bakverk. B...   Handel  Sekk    Trond Olsen JA          xxx                         xxx                 xxx
```

As you can see most columns are empty here. X, XX and XXX is a form of grade-system, but for some columns the content is instead "yes" or "no".

And as I said, the first 10 columns are information about that product, the other 40 is different characteristics (and it's those I wanna work with for one given product).

Comment: Is there some way to classify the ingredients, to know which columns _should_ apply?  Say, viscosity, (how 'quickly' a liquid flows) which (probably) isn't applicable to flour.  This is going to change how your database is designed, for the eventual destinations.  You will _probably_ be able to do everything SQL side, but I'm going to reccommend adding a autoincrement key to your import table (which should otherwise be _identical_ to the passed file).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit as if you'd like to convert the table you have into two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredients
(
    g1           ...,
    gruppe       ...,
    ug1          ...,
    undergruppe  ...,
    artnr        ... PRIMARY KEY,
    artikkel     ...,
    beskrivelse  ...,
    status       ...,
    enhet        ...,
    ansvar       ...,
    prisliste    ...
);
```

I've opted to guess that the `artnr` is the primary key, but adapt what follows to the actual primary key.  This table contains the eleven (though your question said ten) columns that are common to all ingredients.  You then have another table which contains:

```
CREATE TABLE IngredientProperties
(
    artnr       ... NOT NULL REFERENCES Ingredients,
    property    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    value       VARCHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(artnr, property)
);
```

You can then load the populated columns from your original table into these two.  At worst, there'd be 40 entries in IngredientProperties for one entry in Ingredient.  You might make '`property`' into a foreign key reference to a defining list of possible ingredient properties (a third table that defines the possible values for the properties - basically, a record of the column names from your original table).  If you add the third table, it might logically be called IngredientProperties (too), in which case the table I called IngredientProperties needs to be renamed.

You can then join Ingredients and IngredientProperties to get the information you want.

I'm not sure that I recommend this solution; it is basically a use of the 'Entity Attribute Value' approach to database design.  However, for extremely sparse information like you seem to have, and when used with the constraint of the third table.

What you can't sensibly do is handle all possible combinations of 40 columns as that number grows exponentially with the number of columns (and is pretty large with N = 40).

Comment: Well written answer, but normalizing the table is a big no-no in this project at the moment.
Because of time constraints we are not to build multiple tables or any own converting, we must use the excel-data as is (this is in the form the client works with their data). And we can't create an admin interface of the same reason.
However I'm pushing to delay the deadline by 1-2 days so that we can put some time building our own csv/excel-uploader. But that is not something we wanna do until we know for sure that building an awesome killer SELECT-SQL instead is impossible.